# Laravel 5.3 Carbon date format is not set on return?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I have my VitalSignSet model:

```
class VitalSignSet extends Model
{
  protected $dates = [
        'datetimetaken',
  ];

  . . .
}
```

Now in my function I have this function which returns the json encoded encounter with the latest vital sign set. (Encounter has a hasMany relationship with VitalSignSet) Before the return though, I would like the `datetimetaken` field to be formatted for human readability, but just for this particular method. (which is why I did not use accessors)

```
public function get(Request $request, Encounter $encounter) {
   // Setting the latest vital sign set
   $encounter->latest_vitals = $encounter->VitalSignSets()
             ->orderBy('datetimetaken','desc')->get()->first();

   // Formatting the date :
   // Works when just returning the date.
   // Does not return in this format when returning the model with the date.
   $encounter->lastest_vitals->datetimetaken->format('M j, Y');

   return $encounter->toJson();
}
```

The above method is accessed from a js ajax request. When I parse and log the response, the datetimetaken format hasn't changed. (still in `YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s` format) But when I return just `$encounter->latest_vitals->datetimetaken;` after formatting, a string is returned with the format I set. But when I return the containing VitalSignSet model `$encounter->latest_vitals;` (json response), the format is in `YYYY-mm-dd`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're only accessing the data object, you're not actually changing it.

Unfortunately, there is no way (that I've been able to find) to edit the format of the `Carbon` instance in the model. This is because Laravel uses the same format to parse the datetime from the database as it does to format it to a string.

Also, you won't be able to just assign the formatted string to the original as Eloquent will try and parse that string (and fail).

One way (if you want/need to keep the key as `datetime`) would be to convert the output to an array, edit the value, and then return that:

```
$latestVitals = $encounter->VitalSignSets()
    ->orderBy('datetimetaken', 'desc')->first();

$encounter->latest_vitals = collect($latestVitals->toArray())
    ->pipe(function ($item) use ($latestVitals) {
        $item['datetimetaken'] = $latestVitals->datetimetaken->format('M j, Y');

        return $item;
    });

return $encounter;
```

If you don't mind changing the key to be something else (e.g. formatted_datetimetaken) you could add an accessor to what ever model is used for you VitalSignSet:

```
public function getFormattedDatetimetakenAttribute()
{
    return $this->datetimetaken->format('M j, Y');
}
```

And then just use `append()` i.e.

```
$encounter->latest_vitals = $encounter->VitalSignSets()
    ->orderBy('datetimetaken','desc')
    ->first()->append('formatted_datetimetaken');
```

Finally, you could simply edit the datetime in your js with something like http://momentjs.com/docs. Assuming your response it assigned to the variable `response`:

```
response.latest_vitals.datetimetaken = moment(response.latest_vitals.datetimetaken, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
            .format("MMM D, YYYY")
```

Hope this helps!